# Show song info in terminal while playing internet radio (FIP radio)

Tags: linux, terminal, music, mpv

I find it convenient to play [FIP radio](https://www.fip.fr/comment-ecouter-fip) in terminal with mpv:

```
mpv http://direct.fipradio.fr/live/fip-midfi.mp3
```

[image]

Can I get more info on the playing song in terminal?

---

**UPDATE no1:**

A friend gave me a script that should list the FIP radio list in terminal.

I think he uses it on a Mac, but the script might work in Linux if changed.

This is the script:

```
import requests

URL = 'http://www.fipradio.fr/livemeta/7'



data = requests.get(URL).json()
level = data['levels'][0]
uids = level['items']
for i in uids:
    step = data['steps'][i]
    print("{title} — {authors} ({anneeEditionMusique}){space:>60}".format(space=' ', **step).encode("utf-8"), end="\r”)
```

That's what my friend gets when running it (if I have understood it right):

[image]

In order to run that in Linux I have created the file `list_fip.py` containing the line

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
```

followed by the lines above.

I have made the file executable, then, in Dolphin, selected the file and, from right-click context menu *Actions>Run in Konsole*. Which gives this:

```
  File "/home/cip/Desktop/fip_titles.py", line 14
    print("{title} — {authors} ({anneeEditionMusique}){space:>60}".format(space=' ', **step).encode("utf-8"), end="\r”)
                                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

---

Comment: If you look carefully at the last double-quotes in `"\r"` it seems you have typed or copied the wrong character. You need the ascii `"`.

Comment: **UPDATE no3:**

The error mentioned in UPDATE no1 above was just caused by a wrong character (`”` needs to be replace with `"`), as @meuh commented.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050266/get-info-from-streaming-radio) stackoverflow answered question is similar. If you look at the data stream from your URL (e.g. using `curl -v`) you will first get a redirect (`302 Moved Temporarily`) to a new URL. From that new URL you will find the header

```
icy-metadata: 1
```

but I did not see any metadata included in the stream. Since this is public radio (in France) you could try asking them to include it.

Your other alternative is to try to scrape it from the web page.  There is one with the player, and another with just the current title. However, it will not be easy as the data is obtained dynamically through javascript.

Comment: I remember somebody mentioned to me a python script that showed such info in terminal - possibly only the [playlist](https://www.fip.fr/archives-antenne); I hope to talk to the man soon about that.

Comment: I will update the question based on the script mentioned above

Comment: I have updated the question with info on a script that was the initial motive to post the question - but I didn't remember all the details when I have posted the question, and only now I can describe what I meant in the first place.

Comment: Please post your comment to my question in your answer please. Also, I will update the question again to ask how to show in terminal that list along with the playing song.